# Trigger query from file in Bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I have multiple create table statements in files (one per file) and need to execute them on Bigquery so that tables are created. How can get these statements executed on Bigquery automatically either through python API or , without having to manually copy table DDL from file to console and execute ?

1. I have created python code that reads file content in string
2. create bigquery client
3. Use client.query() function to pass table DDL and get table created.

I am looking for better approach, without having to open and read file contents to string

Comment: I think for this kind of use case, it’s the best approach to use the BigQuery Python client and execute each query. What is the problem to open multiple file as string ? (You have a many files ?) In BigQuery and SQL you can also execute several queries in the same file. This scenario is it possible for you ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have different folders, each corresponding for one dataset. I want to run through them and create tables from each SQL file present in folders. I have roughly 200 files per folder.